# Three Js Website not working on Ios devices

Tags: ios, three.js

I have created a small website which has multiple 3d models. I am using Three Js to add these 3d models into it. My largest 3d model size is around 50mb and I have used multiple canvas to display different 3d models at different places in my website. But whenever I try to open the website on my personal ios device(IPhone 14), I get errors like:

> Aw snap Something Went Wrong

On some IOS devices, the device will keep refreshing itself and display the message "a problem repeatedly occurred … ".

> a problem repeatedly occurred …

This issue is NOT occurring on Android devices and on PC, only mobile iOS seems to be affected.

I found similar issue discussion on this:
https://forum.babylonjs.com/t/ios-crashing-issue-severe/32981

I am not sure if it still is an issue between WebGl and Apple's ios. What can I do to mitigate this issue.

Comment: How do you use your canvases? I have encountered a similar problem on iOS devices when generating large textures as HTML canvases, due to iOS having some arbitrary memory limitation for canvases, which is far smaller than the actually available memory. Does this sound familiar to you? It's only a wild guess, but I can't do more without seeing your code.